# How to kill a java application by it's process id from windows cmd?

Tags: windows, process, taskkill

when i run the command: `taskkill /f /pid 16140`

I get this : `ERROR: The process "16140" not found.`

Comment: how you know the pid is 16140?

Comment: A) this is not a Java question B) how do get to that pid number? You see, probably that number is wrong?

Comment: You should ask [here](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).

Comment: you can get the PID from Task manager,  make sure you use the right pid.

Comment: Step 1. `jps`. Step 2. Your current command.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on `Name` column in `Task Manager`, check `PID` to show PID of processes, then execute `taskkill /pid {PID}`.
Note that some processes cannot be terminated by `taskkill`, for example Task Manager.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can kill a process by the process ID (PID) or by image name (EXE filename).

Open up an Administrative level Command Prompt and run tasklist to see all of the running processes:

```
C:\>tasklist

 Image Name                     PID Session Name        Mem Usage
 ========================= ======== ================ ============
 firefox.exe                  26356 Console             139,352 K
 regedit.exe                  24244 Console               9,768 K
 cmd.exe                      18664 Console               2,380 K
 conhost.exe                   2528 Console               7,852 K
 notepad.exe                  17364 Console               7,892 K
 notepad.exe                  24696 Console              22,028 K
 notepad.exe                  25304 Console               5,852 K
 explorer.exe                  2864 Console              72,232 K
```

In the example above you can see the image name and the PID for each process. If you want to kill the firefox process run:

```
C:\>Taskkill /IM firefox.exe /F
```

or

```
C:\>Taskkill /PID 26356 /F
```

The /f flag is kills the process forcefully.  Failure to use the /F flag will result in nothing happening in some cases.  One example is whenever I want to kill the explorer.exe process I have to use the /F flag or else the process just does not terminate.

Answer (score 1):

```
taskkill /im myprocess.exe /f
```

The "/f" is for "force". If you know the PID, then you can specify that, as in:

```
taskkill /pid 1234 /f
```

Lots of other options are possible, just type taskkill /? for all of them. The "/t" option kills a process and any child processes; that may be useful to you